# Проблемы с кодировкой того, что выводится из базы данных MySQL. Не подскажете, как устранить?

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

Здравствуйте пишу скрипт вывода из базы данных таблицы:

```
<?php
   
 
$connection = mysqli_connect($sqlserver, $sqluser, $sqlpass, $sqlbase);

    
    if (!$connection) {
        echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL<br>";
        echo "<br>Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
        echo "<br>Текст ошибки error:" . mysqli_connect_error();
        exit;
    }



$query = "SELECT * FROM architect";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$returned = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
mysqli_free_result($result);
    print_r($returned);

echo $returned['id'];
echo $returned['Характеристки'];
?>
```

Получаю вот такой результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, если просто вывести из файла с кодом надпись на русском языке, то все работает хорошо.. кодировкой сравнения в базе данных установлена utf-8, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема! Хостинг, на котором делаю сайт - Мак Хост..

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию `iconv`. Документация [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php).

`$returned = iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));`

Comment: А может просто кодировку соединения надо настроить?

Comment: Androeed, спасибо! Попробую..

Comment: u_mulder, конечно, так правильнее, но у меня везде стоит одна и та же, а результат - на картинке..

Comment: Я просто предложил решение. Не более.